# using jolt to transform empty field

Tags: jolt

my json looks like this

```
{  
    "group":{  
        "personnel":[  
            {  
                "member":{  
                    "id":"1",
                    "name":"John"
                }
            },
            {  
                "member":{  
                    "id":"2",
                    "name":"Doe"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and the expected output for this is

```
[  
    {  
        "id":"1",
        "name":"John"
    },
    {  
        "id":"2",
        "name":"Doe"
    }
]
```

but, there's also some time when the json is empty like so:

```
{}
```

for this, I want the output to be

```
[]
```

my spec looks like this

```
"spec":{  
    "group":{  
        "personnel":{  
            "*":{  
                "*":"[]"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but this doesnt work on the second case where json is empty, it'll just return null. do I need to add anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tad clunky but this works.

Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "group": {
        "personnel": {
          "*": {
            // write to a temp array so that we can 
            //  default it into existence later if needed
            "*": "temp[]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      // If "temp" does not exist, make it be an empty array
      "temp": []
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      // write value at "temp" to the root level
      "temp": ""
    }
  }
]
```